# Where did all the time related information go from Revision history?

Tags: bug, status-completed, revisions-list, timestamps

Revision history no more shows the time related information for revisions. The issue seems to be everywhere - Ask Ubuntu, SO, Meta SO - everywhere.

[image: no time information]

Comment: [Oops.](http://jsfiddle.net/AYPpF/82/embedded/result/)

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's Shog9's fault!  I knew it!

Comment: @Servy How do you pronounce Shog9 ?

Comment: @returnPhaDaPhunk *shrug

Comment: @return PhaDaPhunk: Shawg ten.

Comment: Boltclock's absolutely right.  Shog9 is the tenth incarnation of teh Order of teh Shogs.  (The Order is zero-based).  His personality changes drastically with every incarnation (Shog4 was my favorite of all the Shogs).  And yes, it really is larger on the inside.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I knew it!

Comment: @RobertHarvey http://prntscr.com/16i1w4 - first try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was fixed in the latest deploy.

My fault, introduced this when fixing another bug where the action verb in those blocks would be incorrect or duplicated.

Comment: You've been making *way* too much rep over fixing bugs lately :P